# How to run a linear hypothesis with interaction?

Tags: r, linear-regression, interaction

My regression is as follow :

```
model <- lm(y ~ a:b + a + b + c)
```

And I want to test whereas the coefficients of my interaction so "a:b" and my variable "a" are equal to 0, or if at least one is different from 0.
I know that I need to use *linearHypothesis*.
But I only managed to test if at least one of the coefficients of my interaction is different from 0.

```
linearHypothesis(model,matchCoefs(model,":"))
```

Do you know how to enter into the *linearHypothesis* my variable "a" ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: ```linearHypothesis(mdl,"a")```? you can read the help page by doing ?linearHypothesis

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the names of the variables you want to test if ar both equal 0.

Dummy data:

```
a = rnorm(100)
b = rnorm(100)
c = rnorm(100)
y = 4 + 1*a + 3*b + 0.5*c + 2*a*b + rnorm(100)

mod = lm(y ~ a:b + a + b + c)

>car::linearHypothesis(mod, c("a","a:b"))
Linear hypothesis test

Hypothesis:
a = 0
a:b = 0

Model 1: restricted model
Model 2: y ~ a:b + a + b + c

  Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F    Pr(>F)    
1     97 657.20                                  
2     95 116.31  2    540.88 220.89 < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

If there was only one of `a` or `a*b` in the model, the null would also be rejected, only if none of them were present. To see that try setting `y = 4 + 3*b + 0.5*c + rnorm(100)` and `y = 4 + 3*b + 0.5*c + a + rnorm(100)`. But the test isn't perfect, if there is too much noise on y, even if `a` and `a:b` were in the model we would accept the null (try `y = 4 + 1*a + 3*b + 0.5*c + 2*a*b + rnorm(100, sd=1000)`)